# Existence of Hausdorff space comprised of disjoint dense subsets

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Problem $13H$ of Willard states -

> For any set $X$, there is a Hausdorff space $Y$ which is the union of a collection $\{Y_x:x\in X\}$ of disjoint subsets dense in $Y$.

I have no idea how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here’s a sketch of one way; I’ve left a few details to be filled in or checked.

Let $Z$ be a Hausdorff space that is the union of two disjoint dense subsets, $D_0$ and $D_1$. For each $x\in X$ let $Z_x$ be a copy of $Z$, and let $Y=\prod_{x\in X}Z_x$. For each $A\subseteq X$ let $\chi_A$ be the indicator function of $A$, and let

$$D_A=\prod_{x\in X}D_{\chi_A(x)}\;.$$

Then $\{D_A:A\subseteq X\}$ is a family of $2^{|X|}$ pairwise disjoint dense subsets of $Y$ whose union is $Y$, which is more than we need: just keep the union of $|X|$ of them. For instance, use

$$Y_0=\bigcup_{x\in X}D_{\{x\}}$$

Comment: I am really interested in the question and eager to work on your hint, sir. Did you simply mean $Z_x=X $ for each $x\in X$ when you say "$Z_x$ be a copy of $Z$" ? Is $Y$ the cartesian product of these $Z_x$ 's ?  I can only think of the space $Z$  with your desired property as $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric and the disjoint dense subsets as rationals and irrationals but won't this involve infinite cartesian product in $Y$? Are there simpler such spaces?

Comment: @user710290: No, I meant that $Z_x=Z$ for each $x\in X$. For $Z$ you can take any Hausdorff space that is the union of two disjoint dense subsets, e.g., $\Bbb R$. Yes, $Y$ is then the Cartesian product of the spaces $Z_x$, so it’s $Z^{|X|}$, the product of $|X|$ many copies of $Z$; if $X$ is infinite, it will indeed be the Cartesian product of infinitely spaces. This was the first example that occurred to me, because it’s easy to get pairwise disjoint dense subsets in a product; there may be simpler ones, but at the moment none occurs to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot  sir.

Comment: @user710290: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott One point is not evident on my side. When you say *just keep the union of $\vert X \vert$ of them*. How are you sure that their union will still be equal to $Y$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: It won’t be. We simply use $Y_0$ instead. All we have to do is find a space with the desired property, and $Y_0$ has it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Here, you gave two examples $Y$ and $Y_0$ which are distinct, or I did not understand the relation?

Comment: Why do you define $Z$, I mean how do we need that? and why the union of $D_A$ is equal to $Y$?

Comment: @schneiderlog: Yes, $Y_0$ and $Y$ are distinct: $Y_0\subsetneqq Y$. Clearly $\bigcup\{D_A:A\subseteq X\}\subseteq Y$. Now let $y=\langle y_x:x\in X\rangle\in Y$ be arbitrary. For each $x\in X$ either $y_x\in D_0$, or $y_x\in D_1$; let $A=\{x\in X:y_x\in D_1\}$. Then for each $x\in X$ we have $\chi_A(x)=1$ iff $x\in A$ iff $y_x\in D_1$, so $$y\in \prod_{x\in X}D_{\chi_A(x)}=D_A\,,$$ and hence $Y\subseteq\bigcup\{D_A:A\subseteq X\}$.

Answer (score 4):

For any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, consider the space $Y=\{0,1\}^\kappa$.  Note that every nonempty open subset of $Y$ has cardinality $2^{\kappa}$, and the usual basis for the product topology consists of $\kappa$ open sets (since any basic open set involves only finitely many of the coordinates).

Now, you can get a dense subset of size $\kappa$ of $Y$ by just picking one point from each nonempty basic open set.  Doing this repeatedly in a transfinite recursion of length $2^\kappa$, you can get $2^\kappa$ disjoint dense subsets of $Y$.  (It will always be possible to choose new points from each nonempty basic open set since at each stage of the recursion, you have picked fewer than $2^\kappa$ points so far.)  So, if you pick $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa\geq|X|$, you can partition $Y$ into $|X|$ dense subsets.